# Would conventional explosives work differently under denser atmosphere?

Tags: science-based, warfare, atmosphere, explosions

**Would conventional explosives work differently under denser atmosphere? (If yes in any noticeable way, then how to roughly calculate the difference)**

Possible clarifications:

- normal, conventional explosives, like ex. dynamite, grenade or aerial bomb  -  [not thermobaric weapon](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/108724/thermobaric-weapons-in-dense-atmospheres)
- roughly the same partial pressure of oxygen, just total atmospheric pressure is 3 times higher thanks to nitrogen
- I'm just interested in pressure wave, I assume that with shrapnels it is easy as they simply lose energy faster by going through denser medium (but please correct me if I am wrong)

Answer (score 7):

Modern explosives self produce the oxygen needed for their functioning (this is why you can fire them underwater), so the oxygen content of the atmosphere has negligible effect.

With 3 times higher pressure you have approximately 3 times higher density. Density is important because the energy transferred by the shock wave increases by decreasing the difference in [acoustic impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_impedance) of the carrying media. I.e. all other being the same, firing a bomb underwater deals more damage to a structure a bigger damage than firing the bomb in air, because the acoustic impedance of water is closer to the acoustic impedance of any solid.

The thing is, air is about 3 order of magnitude less dense than solids or liquids, or to put it in layman terms, it is a factor 1000 less dense. Thus, even multiplying the density by 3, you are barely scratching that 1000: the pressure wave will produce roughly the same damage.

If you want to go the math way, given two media, 1 and 2, the Transmitted acoustic power when going from 2 to 1 is given by $T=1-$$Z_1-Z_2 \over {Z_1 + Z_2}$$=$$2Z_2 \over {Z_1 + Z_2}$, where Z is the acoustic impedance.

As you can see, if you triple $Z_2$ you are slightly increasing the transmitted power.

To have a ballpark figure, let's say that $Z_1=1000$, $Z_2=1$ and $Z^*_2=3$.

$T=$$2Z_2 \over {Z_1 + Z_2}$$=$$2 \over 1001$$=0.1\% $

$T^*=$$2Z^*_2 \over {Z_1 + Z^*_2}$$=$$6 \over 1003$$=0.59\% $

Incidentally, this is why one get spread with gel before getting an echo scan: to make some ultrasound reach the inner of the body.

Comment: I don't think that acoustic impedance isn't _quite_ the thing you care about here; a powerful shockwave reflecting off an object still imparts a considerable impulse to it, no?

Comment: (a little further investigation suggests that shockwaves behave somewhat differently to vanilla acoustic waves at interfaces, but I suspect that most of the useful research on this matter is not public, military research being what it is)

Comment: Your math shows 6 times the effect of the denser atmosphere.  While the energy transfer of neither is very efficient, one is substantially less efficient.

Comment: While not a shock wave, sound travels far better in a denser atmosphere.

Comment: I think you simply truncated your calculations instead of rounding. Your first answer should be 0.1998%, your second be 0.5982%. Rounding both to the first sig digit to match the numerator, you should get 0.2% and 0.6%. Which is much more sensible when you recall your Z2's are in the ration of 3.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, energy is delivered by the pressure wave. And my calculation above shows how much of that energy is transmitted. The remaining part is reflected.

Comment: I don't want to dive deep into math, but effect of air pressure/density is actually much more pronounced than a fraction of 1%. This [article](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/9acd/93bdab0032a0c5608ee807774cc94824ccfe.pdf) suggests that blast pressure should differentiate by 10-100%

Comment: History of US Civil War: bombs set off near or at submarines did not damage the submarine body significantly, **but** the transmitted shockwave into the interior atmosphere was sufficient to crush the occupants to death.